# How can I change the way a word is broken over multiple lines without changing what gets copy-pasted?

Tags: html, css, unicode

I have a wide table with a lot of domain names in it. In order to make things play nicely on narrow displays like my monitors in portrait mode, I thought it would be enough to add some zero-width spaces along the way.

```
{
  use charnames ':full';
  $very_long_token =~ s/[_.-]/\N{ZERO WIDTH SPACE}$1/g;
}
```

I remember doing this in a Word document with technical documentation in it and it really improved the layout of the tables there. Word was also nice enough to swallow the zero width spaces when copying text, so I could both have an acceptable layout and text that copy-pastes correctly.

Browsers aren't that nice enough, and if you try and use 'google.​com' as if it was 'google.com', you're probably gonna have a bad time.

```
$ dig google.​com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-11ubuntu1-Ubuntu <<>> google.​com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 741
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4000
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.\226\128\139com.        IN  A
```

↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ *whoops*

Can I achieve the same effect, perhaps through some CSS majicks, without actually affecting the text that a user copy-pastes from the page?

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to write a full, tested answer, but it sounds like you may be looking for `word-break` http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp

Comment: @gaynorvader that has the same cosmetic effect of adding zero width spaces between each and every character. That's not what I'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [the `<wbr/>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr), as mentioned by Mr Lister.

```
$very_long_token =~ s|([_.-])|<wbr/>$1|g;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than inserting invisible unicode characters, the solution is to use markup.
Put spans around the words you don't want to break inside of, and use `word-break: break-all` for the container (as per @gaynorvader's comment).

Please note that there shouldn't be anything between the spans. No spaces, no returns. That way, there won't be anything extra that gets copied along with the content.

```css
div {word-break:break-all;}
div span {word-break:normal; white-space:nowrap;}
```

```html
<div><span>http://</span><wbr/><span>verylongsubdomain.</span><span>evenlongerdomainname.</span><wbr/><span>com/</span><wbr/><span>andaridiculouslylongfolder/</span><wbr/><span>withasimilarlylongfilename.</span><wbr/><span>txt</span></div>
```

Comment: Does this look correctly to you? The snippet... breaks between 'htt' and 'p://verylongsubdomain' and nowhere else. Chrome 46.

Comment: Got it working now in Chrome as well; see my edit. Sorry about earlier!

Comment: No worries. But... is playing with word-break and white-space even necessary now? The wbr tags seem to be enough on its own. :)

Comment: They may be necessary for browsers that don't support `<wbr/>`.