# Table word warp not breaking onto new line

Tags: html, css, datatables, html-table

Having a strange issue when in jquery datatables where a column will resize and wrap contence when it contains a url like "http://foo.bar.co.uk?test=true&derp=reallyLongParam12345678901234578" it breaks it onto 2 lines at the ? however when it contains a link like "http%3A%2F%2Fdirectproducts.go2cloud.org%2Faff_c%3Foffer_id%3D149&aff_id=1041&aff_sub=white_bluepreland"

It doesn't know how to split this.

Is there anyway to specify more characters that it can split to the next line with as it is causing my table to be wider than the screen.

Note
The badly formated url has been fixed and is just an example

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33677791/1016716) help?

Comment: Thanks @mr-licter this helped by using word-break: break-all it can now break anywhere